# Range in reverse order?

Tags: regex

The following regex is failing on me;

```
[Aa][æ-åÆ-Å].*
```

But this regex is not failing

```
[Aa][v-zV-Z].*
```

It is only when æ-å is used (danish carachters). Im puzzled why?

The error i am getting it

```
parsing "[Aa][æ-åÆ-Å].*" - [x-y] range in reverse order.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`æ` is character code 145, while `å` is character code 134, so you're effectively saying give me the characters between character codes 145 and 134 which doesn't work since the lower bound is greater than the upper bound.  The same is true for `Æ` to `Å`.

Here's one chart of character codes that can help you determine the RegEx you need to create instead:

http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 3):

`[Z-V]` would fail just the same - you need the letters sorted.
 For example: Æ is U+00C6, and Å is U+00C5, they should be reversed (or you can just remove the `-`, there are no letters between them)...

If at all possible, try to use [Unicode character properties](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop) instead of trying to define ranges manually. For example, `\p{L}` will match all letters.